# Retrieving fields in from Mysql connection returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format' error

Tags: python, mysql

I am new to Python and am trying to retrieve data from a MariaDB. Using the example found on the [official documentation](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-connect-python-programs-to-mariadb/) and tweaking with my own columns like this returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Heres what my code looks like:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id, name FROM playlists")

for id, name in cursor:
    print("ID: {}, Name: {}").format(id,name)
```

Can someone explain why I'm getting this error? and whether I'll need to declare each column name in the for loop? (where it says `for id, name in cursor`

Comment: `print("ID: {}, Name: {}".format(id,name))` misplaced `)`

Comment: @Nick Could you turn this into the answer? This has worked, I would really appreciate it if you could answer the second part which is whether I need to declare each column name in the for loop, (it looks like you do from my testing)

Comment: It's just a typo. As to the second part, I *think* (not an expert here) you can use a cursor type of `SSDictCursor` on your connection, then use e.g. `for row in cursor: print(row['id'])`

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues here.  one you need to save the output of the `cursor.execute` to a variable.

Second, you need to loop through the response.  See below for an example:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.cursor import MySQLCursor

db = mysql.connector.connect(option_files='my.conf', use_pure=True)

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT id, name FROM playlists")

# iterate over result
for row in cursor:
    print("ID: {}, Name: {}").format(row[0],row[1])

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: Does `row[0]` and `row[1]` indicate the rows or the columns within a row?

Comment: the columns within the row.  each row of data returned is an array of columns.